# How to pass multiple states in Router Link (Menu Navigation) in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a sidebar menu that uses the state to define the items in the menu, and now I want to make each item in the menu to navigate to a specific component.

The concept of my code is similar to this one:

https://codepen.io/mrhamburger/pen/XzjXGb?editors=0110

I tried to manipulate MenuItem function, and add Link tag. However, I don't know how to pass the state of menuItems, in MenuItem function,
Because each item in the menuItems should navigate to a specific component.

```
 class MenuContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

this.state = {
  activeItem: '',
  activeItemPosition: 0,
  activeItemColor: '',
  menuItems: [
    { text: 'Home' },
    { text: 'Gallery' },
    { text: 'About' },
    { text: 'Blog' },
    { text: 'Contact' },
  ],
}

this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }




function MenuItem(props) {
 return (
     <div 
        className='menu-item'
        id={ props.item.text }
        onClick={ props.handleClick(props.item.text) }
      >
    // I tried to add Link here instead of the below
     { props.item.text.toUpperCase() }
    </div>
      )
                       }
```

My problem is I want to add routing, and  so when someone clicks on any item, they will go to another page. I just didn't know how to pass the changing states using  tags, because each state should go to another page when pressed in the MenuItem function I suppose where the changes can be made.

Please, I am stuck at this stage, would really appreciate if you could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: You simply in general cannot do `onClick={ props.handleClick(props.item.text) }`. Either you would do `onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.item.text)}` or have an intermediary function in this functional component that calls `props.handleClick` with the appropriate value passed.

Comment: The purpose of this one is to change the style of active div, there is another function handleClick which contains the state.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are using the handler correctly in `MenuItem`. First change the contents of `onClick`:

```
function MenuItem(props) {
  return (
    <div 
      className='menu-item'
      id={ props.item.text }
      onClick={ () => props.handleClick(props.item.text) }
    >
      { props.item.text.toUpperCase() }
    </div>
  )
}
```

The next issue is that handleClick is for some reason returning a function inside this handler and also attempting to reference `e` which is not being actually passed to `handleClick()`. Change `handleClick()` to just the following:

```
handleClick(activeItem) {    
  this.setState({
    activeItem,
    activeItemPosition: document.getElementById(activeItem).offsetTop,
     activeItemColor: window.gtComputedStyle(document.getElementById(activeItem)).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
  })
}
```

Making the above changes activated the state/style transition on click. If you actually need to `e.preventDefault()`, you can update `MenuItem` to pass `e` as well:

```
onClick={ (e) => props.handleClick(e, props.item.text) }
```

Then `handleClick()` would have a changed signature of:

```
handleClick(e, activeItem) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // ... rest of function
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you. But actually my problem is I want to add routing, and <Link > so when someone clicks on any item, they will go to another page. I just didn't know how to pass the changing states using <Link /> tags, because each state should go to another page when pressed in the MenuItem function I suppose where the changes can be made.

Comment: You should update your question and example to include the use of React router. The answer is going to look very different with routing included. That being said you can absolutely pass state to routes via Link components https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object and you can also use NavLink to track “active” routes/links.